# Jquery show div if ANY of checkboxes with same target is checked, otherwise hide the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a form with checkboxes which each have 'data-target' attribute to select a hidden div to show when checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" class="show-div" data-target="div-1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" class="show-div" data-target="div-2" value="2"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" class="show-div" data-target="div-2" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" class="show-div" data-target="div-2" value="4">    

<div id="div-1" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="div-2" class="hidden"></div>
```

The javascript is as follows:

```
$('input.show-div').on('change', function() {
       var source = $(this);
       var target = $('#' + source.attr('data-target'));
       if (this.checked) target.show();
       else target.hide();
});
```

This works obviously with the first checkbox or if check/uncheck only one of the last three. What I'd like to achieve is that if any of the checkboxes with same target div is checked, then show it, otherwise hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use currently checked checkbox attribute `data-target` to find if any other checkboxes with same attribute are checked in if condition:

```
$('input.show-div').on('change', function() {
   var source = $(this);
   var target = $('#' + source.attr('data-target'));
   if ($('input[data-target='+source.attr('data-target')+']:checked').length) target.show();
   else target.hide();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7uto01x5/)**

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. I figured it's as simple as rewriting that condition, just didn't have the skills to write that selector.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**
**[Working Demo Click -Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/gm5hdor0/)**

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" class="show-div" data-target="div-1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" class="show-div" data-target="div-2" value="2"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" class="show-div" data-target="div-3" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="group[]" class="show-div" data-target="div-4" value="4">    

<div id="div-1" class="divCls hidden">1</div>
<div id="div-2" class="divCls hidden">2</div>
    <div id="div-3" class="divCls hidden">3</div>
    <div id="div-4" class="divCls hidden">4</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divCls").hide();
    $('input.show-div').on('change', function() {
            $(".divCls").hide();
        $(".show-div:checked").each(function(){
            //alert($(this).attr('data-target'));
            $("#"+$(this).attr('data-target')).show();
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: @teeraina -  Check out the Link - It's working perfect !